# Cannot assign certain string to variable

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to send the string `IDENTITY(1,1)` if certain conditions are met, this one part of the code keeps not working. After looking at everything else I found out the problem was that the variable that was supposed to be storing `IDENTITY(1,1)` was not storing anything and I can't get it to store that particular string.

I have tried:

```
string := "IDENTITY(1,1)"

f4::
send %string%
send "hi"
return
```

and

```
string = IDENTITY(1,1)

f4::
send %string%
send "hi"
return
```

The <kbd>f4</kbd> send was so that I didn't have to rerun the entire process just to test this one string. Also the "hi" is just to verify it is sending correctly, so far it always sends hi.

The code is above and the context doesn't matter since it will not save the variable to begin with, though I can show more if it would help.

I expect to be able to use it like this:

```
string = IDENTITY(1,1)
send %string%
output : IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Comment: Both of your attempts worked just fine for me. As the problem likely lies elsewhere, we may need to see the rest of your code and know the context with which it's being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should give you the desired output. Your issue likely stems from the fact that you're doing the `f4` label all in the same line.

```
string := "IDENTITY(1,1)"
f4:: send %string%
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. when I print it nothing is output

Comment: Try inserting `msgbox %string%` in the middle. If the message box appears with the correct output, then it must be something with the `f4` bind or the program you're trying to print it. Have you tried using other keybinds to see if they work? Using the keybind works in notepad for me; can you attempt there too? If these don't work, post your full code so we can try taking a deeper look at this.

Comment: I was able to get it working by just sending IDENTITY(1,1) without doing variables.